# Ubuntu icons are very very large

Tags: icons

I am using Ubuntu 23.04. My Ubuntu tool bar icons are very large. On Ubuntu 22.10, it wasn't like that. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: This comment is to note that there is a similar question [Just upgraded to 23.04 and now my System Menu Icons are huge. How do I return them to normal size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1477968/just-upgraded-to-23-04-and-now-my-system-menu-icons-are-huge-how-do-i-return-th)

Comment: I have an stock Ubuntu 23.04 running in a VM. [It looks a bit different from yours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Omv0X.jpg). Could you edit your question and add the changes you have done to your dekstop/Gnome?

Comment: Please add system information, notably the graphics card you use.