# Just upgraded to 23.04 and now my System Menu Icons are huge. How do I return them to normal size?

Tags: system, menu

### Large System Menu Icons

[image]

Pretty simple issue. Can't seem to find anything similar to it. I restarted with no luck. Is there a way to customize the System Menu?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I'm using a 1920x1080 screen and that's what my resolution is set to.

I have fractional scaling set to 125%. I've tried adjusting that back and forth and it has no effect.

No other areas of the UI are experiencing this issue.

EDIT2:

I'm running on a HP 15-dy2075tg (i5-1135G7 with integrated graphics)

I have made no changes to the base system. The dock looks different because I simply moved the dock in Settings -> Ubuntu Desktop -> Dock

### Screenshot of whole desktop

[image]

Comment: It's not the resolution. I'm using a 1920x1080 screen laptop and that's the resolution I'm at. No other icons are oversized like that. I've even tried adjusting the scale (and fractional scaling) and it doesn't affect those icons.

Comment: This comment is to note that there is a similar question [Ubuntu icons are very very large](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1477693/ubuntu-icons-are-very-very-large)

Comment: I have an stock Ubuntu 23.04 running in a VM. [It looks a bit different from yours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Omv0X.jpg). Could you edit your question and add the changes you have done to your dekstop/Gnome?

Comment: Please add system information, notably the graphics card you use.